# PHP Access data from an API

Tags: php, api

I'm new to PHP so I am trying to build a simple app that will allow a user to enter a country that will use an API to get data and display it to the user.

The API I'm using https://api.covid19api.com/summary

I can get the info I want by referencing the index

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
$corona = json_decode(  $data, true);

$cdata = $corona['Countries'];

$cdata2 = $cdata[0];

$cdata3 = $cdata2['Country'];

echo "<br>Country : ";
echo ($cdata2["Country"]);

echo "<br>Total Confirmed : ";
echo ($cdata2["TotalConfirmed"]);

echo "<br>Total Deaths : ";
echo ($cdata2["TotalDeaths"]);

echo "<br>Total Recovered : ";
echo ($cdata2["TotalRecovered"]);
```

[image]

My problem is allowing a user to enter a country and getting the data for that country, Total Confirmed, Total Deaths, etc

To allow a user to enter a country and get the data I was trying

```
$corona1 = $corona['Countries']->Country;
print_r($corona1);
```

but I get an error Warning: Attempt to read property "Country" on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\catest\corona.php on line 80:

[image]

I don't understand why as I can see Country is inside the Countries object when looking at the JSON output of the API usin Postman
[image]

Comment: rtm: [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the second param being true will make it an array, so you should access like `$corona1 = $corona['Countries']['Country'];` and if you left out the option, it would be `$corona1 = $corona->Countries->Country;`, not a mix of both, unless you pass into a [ArrayObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)

Comment: The `Country` is array key inside each item of `Countries`. You have to use something like `foreach()` loop to access them or to access specific index use something like this `$corona['Countries'][0]['Country'];`.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$corona1 = $corona['Countries']['Country'];
```

because your using json_decode() second parameter true, that will convert whole object into associative array

maybe it will helpful

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had tried this, sorry forgot to add it as something I attempted in my question. using that I get Warning: Undefined array key "Country" in C:\xampp\htdocs\catest\corona.php

Comment: yes, becasue you are getting multuple countries objects, so if you want to get print first country then you have to write $corona1 = $corona['Countries'][0]->Country;
print_r($corona1);